# Vert.X 4 Web OpenAPI Router blockingHandler

Tags: vert.x, openapi

Why does the RouterFactory of the vertx-web-openapi (released with vert.x 4.0.0-milestone5) not support blockingHandlers?

e.g.

```
routerFactory.operation("getPet").handler(Server::get); // this is supported
routerFactory.operation("getPet").blockingHandler(Server::get); // this is not supported
```

Since pretty much all my routes have SQL connections in the back it means a lot of boilerplate to call vertx.executeBlocking every time.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily create a blocking handler with little boilerplate wrapping your handler in a `io.vertx.ext.web.impl.BlockingHandlerDecorator`:

```
routerBuilder
  .operationId("myOperation")
  .handler(new BlockingHandlerDecorator(handler, true));
```

No need to manually invoke `vertx.executeBlocking`.

Comment: Thank you this is what I was looking for.

Comment: Mind if I ask if the same thing exists for a handler throwing an exception?

Comment: If an handler throws an exception, you should be able to recover it from `failureHandler` of a specific operation, or router global failureHandlers (with status code 500)

Comment: my problem is that I cannot pass it in the .handler() method if it throws a checked exception. I currently have my own utility method written that catches all checked exceptions and then makes the handler fail, it works but looks like a weird workaround for me.

Comment: I see what you mean. In general, vertx-web tries to not handle for you checked exceptions, because it kinda defeat the whole purpose of checked exceptions, which is "you should handle your exceptions". The pattern you're following doesn't sound like a workaround to me, but more "works as intended". Another solution is to wrap all checked in unchecked, but it again defeats the purpose of checked exceptions.

Long story short, when you can, don't use checked exceptions :)